# Android - Binding adapter not working

Tags: android, kotlin, picasso, android-binding-adapter

I have create a binding adapter to display picture with picasso, but it doesn't work. I have the following error :

> Found data binding errors.
>   ****/ data binding error ****msg:Cannot find the setter for attribute 'app:loadPicture' with parameter type java.lang.String on
>   android.widget.ImageView.
>   file:/home/groupevsc.com/mathieu_labar/Documents/Projects/android-jetpack/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_detail_movie.xml
>   loc:27:31 - 27:52 ****\ data binding error ****

Here is my binding adapter :

```
object CommonBindingUtil {

    @JvmStatic
    @BindingAdapter("loadPicture")
    fun loadPicture(view: ImageView, text: String) {
        Picasso.with(view.context)
                .load(text)
                .error(R.drawable.ic_movie_24)
                .fit()
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_movie_24)
                .into(view)
    }

}
```

And my XML has attribute "app:loadPicture" :

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/picture"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/material_image_simple_width"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_movie_24"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:loadPicture="@{viewModel.movie.Poster}"/>
```

Here is my GitHub repository:
https://github.com/mlabar/android-jetpack/tree/tech_ajout_databinding

Would anyone have an idea to solve my problem?

Thank you!

Comment: does it help if you add `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` to your `build.gradle`?

Comment: i don't think it is right but change name `app` to other for loadpicture attribute.

Comment: can u send the full xml file?

Comment: @fightingCoder https://github.com/mlabar/android-jetpack/blob/tech_ajout_databinding/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_detail_movie.xml

Comment: @Blackbelt Thank you for your reply, i will try :)

Comment: May be because you declare your binding adapter inside an object instead of a regular class?

Answer (score 27):

Thank you @Blackbelt to solve my problem, i have added "kotlin-kapt" in all my `build.gradle` modules:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my code

```
@JvmStatic
    @BindingAdapter({"bind:loadPicture"})
    fun loadPicture(view: ImageView, loadPicture: String) {
        Picasso.with(view.context)
                .load(loadPicture)
                .error(R.drawable.ic_movie_24)
                .fit()
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_movie_24)
                .into(view)
    }
```

for more details see my project on  [GitHub](https://android.jlelse.eu/loading-images-with-data-binding-and-picasso-555dad683fdc)

Comment: Than you for your reply. I tried, but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Change your **MovieViewModel** class like this:

```
class MovieViewModel(private val movie: Movie) : Observer, BaseObservable() {

    init {
       Movie.addObserver(this)
    }
    val Poster: String
        @Bindable get() {
            return Poster.name
        }
}
```

And **Movie** class like this:

```
class Movie: Observable() {
    var Title: String = ""
        set(value) {
            field = value
            setChangedAndNotify("Title")
        }
    var Year: String = ""
        set(value) {
            field = value
            setChangedAndNotify("Year")
        }
    var imdbID: String = ""
        set(value) {
            field = value
            setChangedAndNotify("imdbID")
        }
    var Type: String = ""
        set(value) {
            field = value
            setChangedAndNotify("Type")
        }
    var Poster: String = ""
        set(value) {
            field = value
            setChangedAndNotify("Poster")
        }
    var Plot: String = ""
        set(value) {
            field = value
            setChangedAndNotify("Plot")
        }

    private fun setChangedAndNotify(field: Any) {
        setChanged()
        notifyObservers(field)
    }
}
```

Make your class context according to your need, run it hope it'll solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the right parameters for binding adapter function.

```
object CommonBindingUtil {

    @JvmStatic
    @BindingAdapter("loadPicture")
    fun loadPicture(view: ImageView, text: String) {
        Picasso.with(view.context)
            .load(text)
            .error(R.drawable.ic_movie_24)
            .fit()
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_movie_24)
            .into(view)
    }
}
```

Here `loadPicture` function expects parameters `imageView` and a String, but here, in your xml your are passing the Object of photo

```
app:loadPicture="@{viewModel.movie.Poster}
```

You should instead write something like this `app:loadPicture="@{viewModel.movie.Poster.url}`