# Android Binding Adapter is not found

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding, androidx

Please someone help me! I am going crazy, this should work. I have the following error message when I try to build my Android project:

```
Android resource linking failed
/Users/slehrbaum/StudioProjects/OneNightComps/Android/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/stripped.dir/layout/fragment_login.xml:17: error: attribute errorText (aka lehrbaum.de.onenightcomps:errorText) not found.
error: failed linking file resources.
```

the error message does mention the errorText attribute. I use the errorText attribute in the xml this way ([full xml here](https://github.com/findusl/OneNightComps/blob/feature/register/Android/app/src/main/res/layout/fragment_login.xml)):

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/usernameField"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/username"
        app:hintEnabled="true"
        app:errorEnabled="true"
        app:errorText="Hi"
        >
        <!--app:errorText="Please provide a username."-->
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:autofillHints="username"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:text="@={viewModel.username}"
            />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

This is the way I have defined errorText in my Kotlin file ([full file here](https://github.com/findusl/OneNightComps/blob/feature/register/Android/app/src/main/java/lehrbaum/de/onenightcomps/view/ViewDataBindingExtensions.kt)):

```
object ViewDataBindingExtensions {
    @JvmStatic
    @BindingAdapter("errorText")
    fun bindErrorText(textInputLayout: TextInputLayout, errorText: String) {
        textInputLayout.error = errorText
    }
}
```

I just don't understand why this happens. Is there some sort of import that I can put in the layout file saying where the BindingAdapter is? Do I have some wrong with my Gradle files? I compared it to the GitHub project in  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51418542/android-binding-adapter-not-working) which apparently got solved and I do not see the difference to my project. According to the answer I should add the Kotlin-kapt plugin to my Gradle build, which I did. I also looked through the rest of the project and compared. To no avail. You can find my whole [build.gradle file here](https://github.com/findusl/OneNightComps/blob/feature/register/Android/app/build.gradle) as well as the rest of the project.

Please help me!

Comment: Have you tried to add `kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:$gradleVersion"`?

Comment: @AntonHolovin I tried now, but it didn't help. I assume I have to add it to the build.gradle of the app project? And the version should be the same as the one of 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:' right? That didn't work for me. But maybe I did something wrong. I pushed it to GitHub you can find it under the link https://github.com/findusl/OneNightComps/blob/feature/register/Android/app/build.gradle

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The problem is connected with the way you pass String value to `app:errorText`.

Use @{``} to pass this value.

Fixed part of fragment_login.xml:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/username"
    app:hintEnabled="true"
    app:errorText="@{`Please provide a username.`}"
    app:errorEnabled="@{!viewModel.usernameValid}">
```

Having `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` in `app/build.gradle` is mandatory.

Comment: You madman. Thank you so much for the idea that the string literal is the problem. I don't understand why I can't pass a string literal, but I don't care since string literals aren't good anyway. I just had it there because I thought it would be easier to test. When I referenced a variable of the viewmodel it finally compiled and worked. I'll mark your answer as correct, you might want to update it for others, your exact solution gives an error `data binding error ****msg:Syntax error: no viable alternative at input '<EOF>'`

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
fun bindErrorText(textInputEditText: TextInputEditText, errorText: String) {
 textInputEditText.error = errorText }
```

Comment: Sadly this doesn't solve the problem. The error message is now on a different line because the TextInputEditText is on a different line but the rest is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason which is not often discussed is you need to have your layout inside "" tag, else databinding doesn't work. I spent an hour for this.